# Apply custom pairwise function in PyTorch

Tags: torch, pairwise

I have two 1D tensors

```
a = tensor([1, 2])

b = tensor([3, 4, 5])
```

I want to compute custom operation pairwise matrix, for example

"a + b" - adds every element from **a** to every element from **b**

```
tensor([4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7])
```

"a / b" - divides every element from **a** by every element from **b**

```
tensor([1/3, 1/4, 1/5], [2/3, 2/4, 2/5])
```

Can this be done efficiently, without for cycles?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that element-wise in a vectorised form.

First bring the operands to broadcastable shapes (You can read about the pytorch broadcasting semantics [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#broadcasting-semantics))

```
a = a.unsqueeze(-1)   # a.shape == (2, 1)
b = b.unsqueeze(-2)   # b.shape == (1, 3)
# the last line is redundant in fact, according to the semantics
```

Then apply the operation you want:

```
c = a / b             # c.shape == (2, 3)
```